# Xcode Orientation change shows unwanted in between state

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation

I have a very strange problem. 
I added orientation to my app for landscape and portrait without many problems and it works. 
However, I noticed something weird. 
When I keep my iPad "horizontal", meaning parallel to the floor, the view shifts in my window in a way that I did not define and it doesn't look good naturally. It shifts to an "in-between" state that I do not want (I don't know how to explain it otherwise). 
Anyone experienced the same problem? And what is the solution to this problem?

For info: I used an observer on orientation change. I think this is where the problem occurred:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

I also used this code, but I didn't have problems with it before:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: 
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                           duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation  
                               duration:duration];

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    self.view=landscapeView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(90));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,1024.0,748.0);
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    self.view=landscapeView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(-90));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,1024.0,748.0);      
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
    self.view=portraitView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(0));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,768.0,1004.0);
} else {
    self.view=portraitView;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(180));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,768.0,1004.0);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the "in between state" is actually the portrait in landscape and vice versa...